# Perforce - how do I delete p4 client settings

Tags: perforce

I accidentally switched the Client and Host fields and now I cannot change it back. If I edit the file that pops up when I run the `p4 client`, I only get a message that the settings were not changed. I want to start over and just delete the settings, but they seem to be persisted somehow even though I uninstalled the application. How can I delete the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was completely wrong about what happened there. `p4 client` creates a new client by default with some automatically filled settings and when the temporary file is closed, it parses it and either creates a new client or edits the existing one.